# Can htaccess be modified to conditionally serve files based on browser type?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, pdf, mime-types

Client has a website that makes heavy use of pdfs, and certain parts of the site depend on the pdfs loading in the browser.

Users browsing in google chrome, however, occasionally cannot view the pdfs.

The issue may be inherent in wordpress, as note here: 
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/pdf-files-and-chrome

In the meantime, I would like to add the following condition to .htaccess:

```
If browser is chrome
   then Set MIMEtype to octet stream
```

This will at least allow unfortunate users to download view the pdfs, rather than loading screens.

From research, I note that the browser can be detected via .htaccess using RewriteCond like so:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Chrome
```

But

```
ForceType application/octet-stream
```

seems to be the only way to the adjust the MIMEtype.

Is there a simple way to do this that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 1):

No, probably not unless you're using apache 2.4 and utilizing the `<If env>` containers. You can use `SetEnvIf` to set an environment variable based on the user agent, but without the `<If>` containers in 2.4, you can't conditionally call `ForceType`.

You may need to force the type in a script or something and route direct file access through that script.